# What happens next?

Tags: quitting

I just switched from part-time to full time. From day one of being a full time employee (hourly not salary) I get 158 hours of PTO. Well I just got offered a better job. What happens if I take 3 weeks of PTO and put in my two weeks notice while on vacation? What happens if I take 3 weeks PTO and never go back to the job?

Comment: There are policies  that sometimes prohibit you from doing such a thing, but it is mostly company specific. Regardless, it would certainly burn bridges and destroy any and all references you did have if you take 3 weeks PTO and never return without even giving a notice.

Comment: I'd take a long hard look at your work agreement/contract to make sure that you 158 hours of PTO aren't curtailed by leaving earlier than the calculation period (usually a year). One things for sure - if you do leave during your vacation, you won't get a good reference from this employer in the future.

Comment: Also - having 158 hours of PTO on day one, and being able to get 3 weeks leave approved on short notice are two very different propositions. If this wasn't already a planned and agreed upon vacation, I wouldn't give 3 weeks to a new member of staff so soon after starting.

Comment: I've worked there over a year and half. I was part-time. Now I am full time and I get the 158 hours on day one of full-time. I am not salary. So what happens if I put in my two weeks Friday. Work one week then go on PTO? Will they allow that? I requested it a month ago.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two Weeks Notice During Holiday Vacation](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/38536/two-weeks-notice-during-holiday-vacation)

Answer (score 2):

In almost all cases, "credited" time off has to be paid back if you leave before working enough hours to earn it. Check your contract and related paperwork.