# Office closed between Christmas and New Years. Giving 2 weeks notice

Tags: united-states, resignation

So, I was just offered a job at another firm. My direct report is out on PTO tomorrow, so I plan to give notice Thursday 12/21, for my last day to be Friday, January 5. Technically about 2 weeks given Christmas and New Years. New company needs me to start on January 8 as that's when their orientation is for the month of January. They need me to start asap.

My problem, our office is closed the week between Christmas and New Years. There is nothing in the company handbook that states two "business" weeks or anything about discounting holidays. The firm I'm going to is NOT closed the same week, so that's a business week for them, and most other companies.

Am I still giving 2 weeks' notice putting in on Thursday 12/21 for my last day to be 1/5 with the office being closed the first week of my notice period?

I feel bad, but I can't risk missing this amazing opportunity.

Comment: Does it make any difference to what you're going to do if somebody here says "no, that's not giving two week's notice"?

Comment: [Two Weeks Notice During Holiday Vacation](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/38536)

Comment: Surely one of the other managers/HR can help you with resigning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two Weeks Notice During Holiday Vacation](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/38536/two-weeks-notice-during-holiday-vacation)

Comment: If you are legally required to give two weeks notice, that's calendar days, not workdays. If your company wanted working days, they could have put "10 working days" in your contract.

Answer (score 8):

> I can't risk missing this amazing opportunity

Well there's your answer. Sometimes a departure from a company doesn't go as well as you'd have liked. But if you have time constraints then there's no real way around that.

> Am I still giving 2 weeks' notice putting in on Thursday 12/21 for my last day to be 1/5 with the office being closed the first week of my notice period?

In theory yes, but I don't know your company or its culture so I can't tell you how that will go over with your management. They may argue, not without merit, that you're not really giving the full two weeks' notice. Your reply to that should be that you are and realise that it's unfortunate that the company is closed for that week but that you are unable to extend your notice period.

As long as you handle your exit professionally and with some tact and grace, this shouldn't burn a bridge. If you're willing and if it's possible/useful you could suggest working through (part of) that vacation week to document or prepare your handover. But that's optional.

In the end, you have to do what's best for you and good companies will recognise that. Sometimes people leave at inopportune times. Sometimes managers are out on extended leave while their reports have to give notice. Sometimes people leave during a busy period when they get offer that's too good to refuse. These things happen and companies make do. As long as you are reasonable and willing to accommodate your former employer to the extent possible this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Read your contract, offer letter, HR policies,  or employee handbook
2. In the US the "two weeks" is almost always voluntary. It's considered "professional & civilized & courteous" but it there is no legal or even strong moral obligation
3. Sometimes employers prefer short notice periods: You are a sitting duck anyway
4. What is considered "appropriate" depends a lot on your circumstances. If you are not currently in a highly critical role on a highly critical project and if your current stuff is reasonably well organized and documented, then employers don't mind much you leaving early.
5. If you are NOT reasonably well organized and documented, now would be a really good time to start doing this, regardless of when you give notice.

So in short: you can walk out whenever you want. You may ruffle some feathers in the process but this depends on the details of your case and it may or may not matter to you.